# Eclipse CDT Debugger not Working

Tags: eclipse, macos, debugging

After a few solid days of researching and searching throughout the internet across all domains, I have failed in my attempt to find a solution to the Eclipse CDT debugger not being able to run. I have tried everything on the web, from installing gdb on my Mac to changing the debug configurations to point to the debugger and still, the debugger doesn't work. Is anyone running Mac OS X El Capitan and Eclipse CDT running into this same problem? Any solutions?

This message occurs when I have not changed the debug settings in Eclipse to point to gdb, which is installed on my Mac:
"Error with command: gdb --version
Cannot run program "gdb": Unknown reason"

This message occurs when I have changed the debug settings in Eclipse to point to 
gdb using the path: "/usr/local/bin/gdb"
"Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:"

I have searched all over the internet and people have been stating that the above actions which I have taken have worked for them, but unfortunately Eclipse CDT debugger still doesn't work even after my changes. People have also suggested that Eclipse needs to supports lldb, but I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me to get Eclipse CDT running with gdb. Thanks.